# es6 classes in Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I am learning the [code sample of es6 with Backbone](https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc-backbone-es6/blob/gh-pages/js/todo-app.js#L184). I am confused by the following codes:

```
class TodoView extends View {
  constructor(options) {
    this.tagName = 'li';
    this.template = _.template($('#item-template').html());
    this.input = '';
    this.events = {
      'click .toggle': 'toggleCompleted',
      'dbclick label': 'edit',
      'click .destroy': 'clear',
      'keypress .edit': 'updateOnEnter',
      'blur .edit': 'close'
    };

    super(options);

    this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
    this.listenTo(this.model, 'destroy', this.remove);
    this.listenTo(this.model, 'visible', this.toggleVisible);
  }
```

I have some questions:

1, Does the position of `super(options)` matter here?
2, Should I move `this.listenTo()` to `initialize()`?
3, How about the [following codes](https://benmccormick.org/2015/07/06/backbone-and-es6-classes-revisited/)?

```
constructor() {
    super({
        tagName:  'li',

        template: _.template(todosTemplate),

        events: {
            'click .toggle':    'toggleCompleted',
            'dblclick label':   'edit',
            'click .destroy':   'clear',
            'keypress .edit':   'updateOnEnter',
            'keydown .edit':    'revertOnEscape',
            'blur .edit':       'close'
        },
    });
}
```

Comment: 1. Yes, it matters, you can't refer `this` before calling `super`. 2. Probably, if this doesn't hurt anything - it may be helpful later, design-wise.

Comment: @estus Thanks. Why ```this``` referred before ```super()``` called in the first piece of code?

Comment: Because the piece of code was written for the transpiler that followed the specs loosely - so did the author. This is a mistake. Try this in current Babel or native ES6 class and you'll see.

Comment: In the context of backbone, you might find this helpful: https://benmccormick.org/2015/04/07/es6-classes-and-backbone-js/